# How to reference hash.values created array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I created a grocery list of hashes, which stores the items and the costs associated with it, which are entered by the user.

I want to add all the values stored in this hash. My initial plan was to convert them into an array and then go from there.

```
hash = {}
entry = " "

while entry != "q"
  print "Enter your item: "
  item = gets.chomp

  print "Enter the associated cost: "
  cost = gets.chomp.to_f

  print "Press any key to continue or 'q' to quit: "
  entry = gets.chomp

  hash[item] = cost  
end

puts "Receipt: "
puts "----------"

hash.each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k} costs $#{v}"
end

puts "----------"
puts "subtotal: "
hash.values
```

How do I reference the new created array made by `hash.values`?

I tried `array.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }`, but it doesn't work since it won't recognize the newly created array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
subtotal = hash.values.inject(0, :+)
puts subtotal
```

In your code you are exctracting the array but you are not using it.

Comment: Yep that worked! Thanks, will accept it as an answer as soon as I can

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

As of Ruby 2.4, you could just use [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) :

```
puts "subtotal: "
puts hash.values.sum
```